# Column "" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

I am attempting to run a sql query that joins some additional tables to populate results and can't seem to get it working the way I want it too. Relatively new to SQL too

Here is my current working query:

```
SELECT
    app_step ->> 'appID' AS "App ID",
    count(tasks.task_id) AS "Total Tasks Started",
    count(tasks.failed_reason_detail) AS "Fix Task Count",
    sum(case when tasks.status='running' THEN 1 else 0 end) AS "Running Count",
    avg(tasks.start_date - tasks.end_date) AS "Average Duration" 
FROM tasks
JOIN teams
    ON tasks.team_name = teams.team_name
WHERE
        teams.is_internal_team = false AND
        tasks.start_date between 
            (SELECT TIMESTAMP 'yesterday' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago') AND 
            (SELECT TIMESTAMP 'today' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago') AND
        (app_step IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY app_step ->> 'appID'
ORDER BY count(app_step ->> 'appID') DESC;
```

Which populates results like:

```
                    App ID                     | Total Tasks Started | Fix Task Count | Running Count | Average Duration 
-----------------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+------------------
 pushbot/calculate/v2                          |               42450 |              0 |             0 | -00:00:00.279624
 pushbot/rename-run/v1                         |               40907 |              0 |             0 | -00:00:00.356639
```

I am trying to add a column from another table to the results
`completed_task_app_rollup_by_day.count AS "Completion Count",`

```
SELECT
    app_step ->> 'appID' AS "App ID",
    count(tasks.task_id) AS "Total Tasks Started",
    completed_task_app_rollup_by_day.count AS "Completion Count",
    count(tasks.failed_reason_detail) AS "Fix Task Count",
    sum(case when tasks.status='running' THEN 1 else 0 end) AS "Running Count",
    avg(tasks.start_date - tasks.end_date) AS "Average Duration" 
FROM tasks
JOIN completed_task_app_rollup_by_day
    ON tasks.app_step ->> 'appID' = completed_task_app_rollup_by_day.app_id
JOIN teams
    ON tasks.team_name = teams.team_name
WHERE
        teams.is_internal_team = false AND
        completed_task_app_rollup_by_day.date between 
            (SELECT TIMESTAMP 'yesterday' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago') AND 
            (SELECT TIMESTAMP 'today' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago') AND
        tasks.start_date between 
            (SELECT TIMESTAMP 'yesterday' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago') AND 
            (SELECT TIMESTAMP 'today' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago') AND
        (app_step IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY app_step ->> 'appID'
ORDER BY count(app_step ->> 'appID') DESC;
```

Which produces: `column "completed_task_app_rollup_by_day.count" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

When I add the column to the GROUP BY - I don't get the results i'm looking for:

EX:

```
                    App ID                     | Total Tasks Started | Completion Count | Fix Task Count | Running Count | Average Duration 
-----------------------------------------------+---------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------+------------------
 pushbot/rename-run/v1                         |                8612 |                2 |              0 |             0 | -00:00:00.356639
 pushbot/rename-run/v1                         |                6459 |                1 |              0 |             0 | -00:00:00.356639
 email/send/v2                                 |                4470 |                1 |              0 |             0 | -00:00:01.69917
 email/send/v2                                 |                3576 |                2 |              0 |             0 | -00:00:01.69917
```

Notice how the app_id section is not unique

Any idea how to include this column in my query without grouping by that column. I've tried doing a sub-query multiple times but no luck. Thanks everyone

Comment: It looks like you have multiple completion count values per App ID.  Which one should your query return, or do you want duplicates in the other columns in order to show all completion count values?

Comment: What flavour of SQL?

Comment: @APH I want all completion count values for each App ID to show up. I need a unique list of app_id's and there corresponding columns ("Total Tasks Started", "Completion count" , etc)

Comment: @ScubaSteve Node sequelize

Comment: It may help to add a [MCVE], including a table showing your desired results.

Comment: If you don't want to group by it, then use it in an aggregate function as the error message suggests, e.g. `sum(completed_task_app_rollup_by_day.count)`